# linking boost library into c++ project

Tags: c++, boost

I had a working project, were I succefully included the boost library. After updating my OS from Ubuntu 17.10 to 18.04, the boost library (boost1.63) was removed and I installed the newer version 1.65.

installation path:

```
$ ldconfig -p |grep boost
libboost_wserialization.so.1.65.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_wserialization.so.1.65.1
libboost_wserialization.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_wserialization.so
... and so on
```

when I want to build the my project using:

```
g++-6     -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/parameterestimatorfordynamicmodels <lots of .o files> -L/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lboost-system -lboost-filesystem -lboost-thread -lboost-chrono -ljsoncpp -lsbml -lsundials_kinsol -pthread
```

I get the error:

```
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: -lboost-system kann nicht gefunden werden
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: -lboost-filesystem kann nicht gefunden werden
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: -lboost-thread kann nicht gefunden werden
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: -lboost-chrono kann nicht gefunden werden
```

-> the libraries are not found

What is the problem?

Comment: N.B. if you set `LANG=C` in the environment before running GCC then you won't have to translate the error messages to English.

Comment: Did you install the -dev boost packages? (look for the includes) Did you clean and rebuild your project? Did you check to see if the boost libs are on the lib path you specified on that command line?

Comment: I installed the package `libboost-all-dev` and it was installed to the path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` which I specify by the command `-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`. And I did clean and rebuild my project